# Kendo UI app.navigate()

Tags: callback, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Can I somehow make kendoUI .navigate() function of the application object to execute synchronously? I haven't found anything, but from behavior it seems to me that it is asynchronous. Or can I maybe somehow provide a callback function?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$.when(app.navigate('views/view2.html')).then( callback() );
```

I want navigation to fully occur, i.e, I want to move to view2.html, and only then to call the callback function. However, my callback function always executes before view2.html is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kendo UI mobile you have the events data-before-show or data-after-show you can call your callback function from one of these events

```
data-after-show = "callback"
```